# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound know when sound stopped

Tags: ios, audio, service, delegates

Im using

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

to play a sound, but I need to know when the sound has stopped playing, so what is the delegate for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)?

> **AudioServicesPlaySystemSound**
>
> Plays a system sound object.

```
void AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (
   SystemSoundID inSystemSoundID
);
```

> **Discussion** This function plays a short sound (30 seconds or less in duration). Because sound might play for several seconds, this
>   function is executed asynchronously. **To know when a sound has
>   finished playing, call the `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion`
>   function to register a callback function**.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410143/audioservicesaddsystemsoundcompletion-callback-method-is-not-called-after-a-few) stackoverflow question might help you to learn how to use this callback.