# How does AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion() work?

Tags: ios, macos, core-audio

I don't understand how the function mentioned above can help me to ensure that some sound has already been played and the next lines of code must be executed? 
What is the role of the callback function (passing as an argument) here? 
What actually such callback function should do?

Comment: does this SO question help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410143/audioservicesaddsystemsoundcompletion-callback-method-is-not-called-after-a-few)

Answer (score 0):

The callback function you specify will be called when the system sound play is complete, so you should put your "next lines" you want executed when the sound is done in that function.  Not after the add-completion OS call.